# Rewrite underscores as hyphens in Joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

Several SEO tests complain about URLs using underscores instead of hyphens in my joomla site. I would like to use a htaccess rewrite rule to change any underscore for a hyphen.

I've tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

But it's not working properly.

I would like to rewrite:
http://domain.com/calendar/icalrepeat.detail/2014/04/23/15/-/name-of-event?filter_reset=1

for:
http://domain.com/calendar/icalrepeat.detail/2014/04/23/15/-/name-of-event?filter-reset=1

Comment: I believe you need to escape the hyphen. `([^\-]*)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters used as operators in Regex with a `\`

```
RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)\-([^\-]*\-.*) $1-$2 [N]
```

Comment: So how would the complete rewrite rule look like?

Comment: Well if all the underscores are to be hyphens, replace `_` with `\-`